# Finding Deleted / Updated record statement from SQL Server transaction Log backup file

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

One of my production server's data was updated / deleted by someone.

I want to find out when the data was deleted or updated, and if it's updated/ deleted then through which statement it was updated (means the query statement details like through which query it is happened).
I have a transaction log file i.e . .trn file.

Answer (score 1):

**Method 1**: If you want to find it from the transaction log backups you can use read the log via`fn_dump_dblog`to get the explicit information. On how to read and use this please refer [Using fn_dblog, fn_dump_dblog](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/using-fn_dblog-fn_dump_dblog-and-restoring-with-stopbeforemark-to-an-lsn/)

Note:

> functn uses this extensively that every time fn_dump_dblog is called,
>   it creates a new hidden SQLOS scheduler and up to three threads, which
>   will not go away (and will not be reused) until a server restart.

**Method 2**: Using the default trace which is enabled by default in SQL server and it can be used to find various such information on altered objects etc. as explained in this article [The default trace in SQL Server - the power of performance and security auditing](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/performance/the-default-trace-in-sql-server---the-power-of-performance-and-security-auditing/)

**Method 3**: You can use third party tool like [ApexSQL Log](http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_log.aspx)(You can give it a try with Trial version , else for full verison you can go for purchase) which is a SQL transaction log reader for forensic auditing and rollback of malicious or inadvertent changes